# Using BRKINT With Pseudo-Terminals

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, serial-port, pseudoterminal

```
$ screen
$ stty -ignbrk brkint
$ sleep 10
```

If I now press [Ctrl-A+b to trigger a serial break](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Break.html), why is no SIGINT sent to the foreground process group `sleep 10`? Are serial breaks not implemented for pseudo-terminals? Or what am I missing?